# Ionic 2 - App not asking if I want to update live or not in debug mode

Tags: ionic2

My ionic app, when I was running command like `ionic cordova run ios --device` use to asking me if I wanted last update of the app. But now, not asking me and make this update, so when I develop I can't see my changes because I have the last deploy in ionic.
Did you know how to disable this in debug mode? Why it doesn't asking me anymore if I want disable update live?

Comment: You mean --livereload?